# How to set a variable and show a component with React Route

Tags: url, react-router

Starting to learn `react-router` I managed to create a few pages (components) that show on different URLs. The first page is a menu page with links to click to get to the other pages. Code is straight forward, after reading some online tutorials. When a URL matches, a component shows:

```
<Route path='/CheckIn' component={ScreenCheckIn} />
```

Now I want to add some variables to the routing process. When a component is selected, also a variable should be set, e.g. for a proper title above the page. I tried this:

```
<Route path='/Search' render={(props) => { 
    this.state.screentitle = 'Zoeken'
    return (<ScreenSearch barcode={this.state.barcode} {...props} />) 
}} />
```

but this does not work. I am reading on `history` but this seems complex and overkill. I just need to show the current URL in another part of the app. Translating such URL to a proper title would be simple programming.

Then I need to pass other bits of data too. E.g. I want an input field that is common to all pages that can be selected by Route's, and pass the input value to the selected component, as a property. Now that would work with the above method.

If I could set a variable depending on the matched route, I could also show or hide the common input field, because the menu page does not need the input field, e.g.:

```
{this.state.screentitle == 'Menu' ?
    null
    :
    <input .... />
}
```

But there are so many other components in the Route API, with subtle differences, that it makes it all a bit confusing.

Is there a simple way to `Route` to a component and also set some variable(s)?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to change the page title dynamically set through props? 
You can try this code

`componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.pageTitle);
    document.title = this.props.pageTitle;
  }`

and you know already how to pass the props in routing

Comment: @tareqaziz It seems strange to me to do routing in the parent, render a child component with routing, and have that child pass its title back to the parent for display. I tried to handle the title entirely in the parent, however, with react-route it seems hard to create a Route that 1) sets a title, and b) renders a component. On the other hand, it is just one title. If there is no easy way, I will just use the first, strange, way, and get it over with. Thanks for your answer anyway